# Node modules error when starting application

Tags: node.js, typescript, runtime-error

I am getting the following error when starting my app.

[image: Errors on startup]

I tried updating node, mongo, and typescript but that didn't help. It was working before until it just stopped suddenly, and I didn't touch any of the files listed in the error.
You can also take a look at `tsconfig.json`

[image: tsconfig.json]

and `tsconfig.build.json`

[image: tsconfig.build.json].

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you updated the dependencies in your current project?

Comment: I just did with yarn upgrade and I got even more errors now, should I revert to how it was or...

Comment: what kind of errors? Are they related to node_modules in your project or something related to upgradation ? you can share the details.

Comment: I hope you can see it here, I copied the whole output. 
https://www.codepile.net/pile/XbEnMVeL

Answer (score 0):

After looking on the logs. I would suggest this:

1. remove node_modules
2. npm i
3. try to run project

Mostly error are related to the conflicts. It might be due to the updation of your angular, node and mongoose version.

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade to your last available versions?